# How to override a specific Spartacus component

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am using the same component twice in Spartacus but with different data.

I am trying to override this component but if I override it with the type code they will both be identical while I need them to still be different.

Is there a way to use a specific id to target a specific instance of the component instead of overriding all of them ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Tommy. What is the component you want to overwrite? Which mechanism did you use to overwrite it? e.g. cmsComponents mapping? or outlets?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, since the two components are the same but have different data, I assume the data would come as input.

In this case, I would suggest using outlets in the app.component.html file. For example:

```html
<ng-template cxOutletRef="section1" >
  <component [inputData]="data1"></component>
</ng-template>

<ng-template cxOutletRef="section2" >
  <component [inputData]="data2"></component>
</ng-template>
```

In this case, they would be rendered in their respective sections but with different data. Does this answer your question?